# best way to load angular-strap modules selectively?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I want to avoid including the whole library into my application:

i.e. `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/v2.3.8/angular-strap.min.js"></script>`

For instance, I tried including `mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip.js.js`, `mgcrea.ngStrap.helpers.dateParser.js`, `gcrea.ngStrap.helpers.dateFormatter.js` and `mgcrea.ngStrap.timepicker.js` but I'm still getting dependency errors (missing module `mgcrea.ngStrap.core`)

For reference here's the library website: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Comment: I would suggest to use requirejs to load the whole library on demand

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer (http://www.requirejs.org/). It'd be helpful if I end up loading the whole library.

Comment: What is the purpose? If the goal is speed you will not gaining anything by opening 5 connections instead of 1; if the goal is size you put a lot of effort into reducing the codebase with perhaps 1k minified.

Comment: Apologies for the late replay. The goal is reduce its size. The minified library is around [80k](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/dist/angular-strap.min.js). I was able to reduce its size to [40k](https://github.com/AngelAlvarado/angular-strap) . Basically I compiled the library using Gulp (removing the unnecessary plugins for my use case)